# Jquery - I have problem with accordion

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

I have done accordion, see the jsfiddle link, when click on the view accordion div will show.

In that accordion div , i have a another block with title "upstage" and "downstage". when accordion div show the inner block comes from the left to right, and hide from the right to left.

How to stop that animation. i need that inner block should place in the right side.

please help me out

Here jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/RNqEs/1/

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? I'm not sure what your issue/desired solution is.

Comment: By the W3C reccomandations: **ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").**  [LINK](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$(".accordionBlock").toggle('fast');
```

to

```
$(".accordionBlock").toggle();
```

to remove the animation. This produces a show/hide effect.